# Meaning of V.R.T. in "The Fifth Head of Cerberus"

Tags: gene-wolfe, the-fifth-head-of-cerberus

"[The Fifth Head of Cerberus](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?41887)" is a set of three inter-twined novellas by Gene Wolfe. The final novella is called *V.R.T.* and is told in a mosaic fashion, dealing with the adjudication of John V. Marsch, who has been arrested in St Croix as a murder suspect and as a suspected spy. In the course of the story we are told how Marsch ventured into the wilds of St Anne, accompanied by a child who claims to be a partial descendant of the St Anne aboriginals.

Among the material reviewed is an exercise book labelled "V.R.T.", which are the initials of the aboriginal child. The "T" is clearly "Trenchard" - the surname of his (human) father. Do we have any indication what the "V" and the "R" stand for?

Comment: Hi, are the initials the full extent of your question?

Comment: @Spencer I would welcome more information, but yes, initially I am interested in what V and R stand for

Comment: Instead of an edit, that could be a partial answer. (It might be as much of an answer as we have!)

Comment: [Speculation](https://ultan.org.uk/desanctifying-victor-trenchard/) that R might be Rodman, the author's own middle name, just as [Number Five's real name is Gene Wolfe](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2821/17). If there's *speculation* among fans, that suggests a definitive answer doesn't exist. I suggest you self-answer this with the Victor that you found and maybe some evidence for possibilities for R such as Rodman.

Comment: @Randal'Thor if you can find a citation to the "some people have suggested" (which people?) I'd be happy to accept it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Following @Randal'Thor's suggestion, I am posting a partial solution to my question (the meaning of the "V"), together with some speculative answers to the remaining part (the meaning of the "R"). If anybody finds a more authoritative answer for the "R" I would be happy to accept their answer though.

Rereading the text in detail when Marsch first meets the Annese beggar "R.T." we find the following dialogue:

> [the father] exclaimed, “Ah, you are a doctor! Look, Victor, our
> visitor is a doctor of philosophy!” and held the card for an instant
> in front of the boy's eyes

So his son is called Victor, and thus the meaning of the "V" initial is indeed revealed, although in a very subtle way.

This just leaves the "R". [Ultan's library](https://ultan.org.uk/desanctifying-victor-trenchard/) (a web resource for the study of Gene Wolfe) makes the comment:

> V.R.T. is Victor R. Trenchard. If the ‘R’ of his middle name is
> Rodman, as some people have suggested, this is an additional
> correspondence, being author Gene Wolfe’s middle name

I do not know who the "some people" are making this suggestion, but it is interesting to note that the fan-base do not have a commonly-accepted answer. So unlike the "V" which came down to noting a particular sentence fragment, it is probably the case that the "R" is unspecified in the book. In that case "Rodman" seems as good a guess as any.

Some go further though. Robert Borski's *Cave Canem* website is now hosted at the [wolfewiki](https://www.wolfewiki.com/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=CaveCanem.Index) and contains an entertaining (though highly questionable!) [account](https://www.wolfewiki.com/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=CaveCanem.Vroyt) of how he deduced that the "R" stands for "Roy". The V.R.T. exercise book contains the text "Rm E2S14 Seat 18." Treating the numbers as a cipher yields R E 2 S N R, which (he asserts) can be interpreted as "2 Roy Emersons, son/senior", since Roy Emerson is the name both of Gene Wolfe's father and first son. Based on this he claims that:

> Can there now be any doubt that VRT is named after both Gene Wolfe's
> father and son and stands for Victor Roy Trenchard?